# Microsoft Surface TouchScreen support?

Tags: touchscreen, surface-tablet

I've got latest Elemenary OS installed and running quite nicely on my Surface Book. Everything is great except there is no touchscreen support. I've read about a custom Kernel called Jakeday Kernel but as a first time Linux user, I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

Is there a driver I can install or is the only solution to install this new kernel? If so, can someone pat me on the head and tell me this is a safe (and fairly simple) thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the Jakeday Kernel kernel and things became unstable so I'm assuming the answer to this question is that there is no answer ;-(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I'd like those of you owning a Surface Pro 4 (it may work on other models/versions as well) that if you have installed the Hera release and then following [Jakeday's](https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface) setup, touchscreen and pen will work fine! You probably need to manually add a new grub entry to boot the new modified kernelm but that's a small thing. You can just copy/paste the original "elementary" entry and change initrd and vmlinuz to the ones build by Jakday's script.